# How to set exp:channel:entries tag to no limit?

Tags: channel-entries

Based on [this](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#limit) link in the documentation, the default limit is 100 if it is not defined.

How do you set it so that it will not have any limits?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No limit is not possible, but you can simply set limit to some ultra-high value, e.g.

```
limit="999999"
```

Comment: Beware you may run into memory issues with very high numbers. I've experienced problems with limits as low as 500.

Comment: Usually, if you need a very high limit, you might want to consider pagination / ajax loading. If needed for export, then you can temporarily up your PHP memory limit.

Answer (score -2):

But I think using pagination is a simplest solution, I also tried with a high number of limit with channel entries tag but didn't work. One can also go with the Ajax pagination for this.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question though...